# Get value in JSON object from external URI

Tags: powershell

In my PowerShell code I have:

```
$retrieveSourceBranchFromBuildURL = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/build/builds/$buildId" + "?api-version=5.0"
```

When I navigate to the URL in the browser I see:

```
{
    _links: {
    self: {
    href: "https://dev.azure.com/something/7720f8d2-bf64-47d9-8b10-53f21220d54d/_apis/build/Builds/46070"
    },
    web: {
    href: "https://dev.azure.com/something/7720f8d2-bf64-47d9-8b10-53f21220d54d/_build/results?buildId=46070"
    },
    sourceVersionDisplayUri: {
    href: "https://dev.azure.com/something/7720f8d2-bf64-47d9-8b10-53f21220d54d/_apis/build/builds/46070/sources"
    },
    timeline: {
    href: "https://dev.azure.com/something/7720f8d2-bf64-47d9-8b10-53f21220d54d/_apis/build/builds/46070/Timeline"
    },
    badge: {
    href: "https://dev.azure.com/something/7720f8d2-bf64-47d9-8b10-53f21220d54d/_apis/build/status/67"
    }
    },
    parameters: "{"system.pullRequest.pullRequestId":"5766","system.pullRequest.sourceBranch":"refs/heads/pb/31333-test-branch/name","system.pullRequest.targetBranch":"refs/heads/master","system.pullRequest.sourceCommitId":"1cf19b95a59478a8554c2c03d65dcefe203529a6","system.pullRequest.sourceRepositoryUri":"https://something@dev.azure.com/something/something%20Suite/_git/client-web","system.pullRequest.pullRequestIteration":"1"}",
}
```

The `$buildInformation` variable:

```
$buildInformation = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $retrieveSourceBranchFromBuildURL -Headers @{Authorization = $pat } -Method Get -ContentType 'application/json'
```

When I output the value of `$buildInformation` I get:

```
 @{_links=; properties=; tags=System.Object[]; validationResults=System.Object[]; plans=System.Object[]; triggerInfo=; id=46079; buildNumber=20190624.3; status=completed; result=succeeded; queueTime=2019-06-24T07:57:05.7271255Z; startTime=2019-06-24T07:57:12.8021227Z; finishTime=2019-06-24T08:12:27.003113Z; url=https://dev.azure.com/embrace/7720f8d2-bf64-47d9-8b10-53f21220d54d/_apis/build/Builds/46079; definition=; buildNumberRevision=3; project=; uri=vstfs:///Build/Build/46079; sourceBranch=refs/pull/5740/merge; sourceVersion=735f7a813c343dbbca5e1d1b3e966e0bad1db762; priority=normal; reason=pullRequest; requestedFor=; requestedBy=; lastChangedDate=2019-06-24T08:14:41.11Z; lastChangedBy=; parameters={"system.pullRequest.pullRequestId":"5740","system.pullRequest.sourceBranch":"refs/heads/master-md/social-create-team","system.pullRequest.targetBranch":"refs/heads/master","system.pullRequest.sourceCommitId":"e744e5c35bc3fd1539d5c49daa29147f048f3276","system.pullRequest.sourceRepositoryUri":"https://embrace@dev.azure.com/embrace/Embrace%20Suite/_git/client-web","system.pullRequest.pullRequestIteration":"5"}; orchestrationPlan=; logs=; repository=; keepForever=False; retainedByRelease=True;
```

When I output the value of `$buildInformation.parameters`:

`Write-Host $buildInformation.parameters`

```
{
    "system.pullRequest.pullRequestId":"5740",
    "system.pullRequest.sourceBranch":"refs/heads/master-md/social-create-team",
    "system.pullRequest.targetBranch":"refs/heads/master",
    "system.pullRequest.sourceCommitId":"e744e5c35bc3fd1539d5c49daa29147f048f3276",
    "system.pullRequest.sourceRepositoryUri":"https://embrace@dev.azure.com/embrace/Embrace%20Suite/_git/client-web",
    "system.pullRequest.pullRequestIteration":"5"
}
```

But when I try to read a value:

`Write-Host $buildInformation.parameters.system.pullRequest.sourceBranch`

The output is empty.

So how do I retrieve the `parameters.system.pullRequest.sourceBranch` value?

Comment: You need to use `'system.pullRequest.sourceBranch'` to access that specific property. By the way, you have a typo in last `Write-Host` (paramater => parameters). Can you list the output of `Write-Host $buildInformation.parameters.parameters`? From the outputs listed I'm not sure about the structure of `$buildInformation` (the output you listed looks like output from `$buildInformation`, not`$buildInformation.parameters`).

Comment: @robdy I messed up the outputs while copy/pasting. Updated the question with the correct data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access the property with 'special characters' in its name, enclose the parameter name inside quotes like so:

```bsh
$buildInformation.parameters.'system.pullRequest.sourceBranch'
```

**NOTE**: The trick here is that the value of `parameters` is inside double quotes. Therefore you might not be able to access the properties under `parameters` the usual way. To workaround it, you can make a conversion directly on `parameters`:

```bsh
$convertedParams = $buildInformation.parameters | ConvertFrom-Json

# Access desired property
$convertedParams.'system.pullRequest.sourceBranch'
```

---

When you access the property like you tried

```bsh
$buildInformation.parameters.system.pullRequest.sourceBranch
```

the structure of your JSON should be like this:

```bsh
PS> $buildInformation = '{
"parameters": {
  "system": {
    "pullRequest":{
      "sourceBranch": "refs/heads/master-md/social-create-team"
      }
    }
  }
}' | ConvertFrom-Json

# Checking output
PS> $buildInformation.parameters.system.pullRequest.sourceBranch
refs/heads/master-md/social-create-team
```

Comment: I think the `$buildInformation.parameters` is not a json object. When I run `$buildInformation.parameters[0]` the output is `{`. When I run `$sourceBranch = $buildInformation.parameters.'system.pullRequest.sourceBranch'
    Write-Host $sourceBranch` the output is ` ` empty. Still.

Comment: Good catch, you need to `ConvertFrom-Json` as I added in the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Got it figured out. I also found out that not every build on Azure has a parameters object. That was kinda dumb.